# Cannot set the height for pdf using ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm converting the records into pdf using 'ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf' dll.

It works fine. But the pdf has huge space at the end of it.

So I used below code to set the height for the pdf.

> pdfConverter.PageHeight = 512

But it is not working.

My code is in below,

```
using ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf;

private static PdfConverter GetPdfConverter()
        {
            PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
            Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            //pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "put your license key here";
            //pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.CustomPdfPageSize =
            //                            new SizeF(200, 100);

            // set the HTML page width in pixels
            // the default value is 1024 pixels

            pdfConverter.PageWidth = 0; // autodetect the HTML page width
            pdfConverter.PageHeight = 512; // autodetect the HTML page width

            // set if the generated PDF contains selectable text or an embedded image - default value is true
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = false;

            // set the PDF compression level
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfCompressionLevel = (PdfCompressionLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfCompressionLevel), "Normal");
            // set if the HTTP links are enabled in the generated PDF
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LiveUrlsEnabled = false;
            // embed the true type fonts in the generated PDF document
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = true;

            // set if the converter should try to avoid breaking the images between PDF pages
            pdfConverter.AvoidImageBreak = true;

            return pdfConverter;
        }
```

Can anyone help me to set the height for pdf using   'ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf' dll.

Comment: Page dimensions  and margins can be specified in inches (in), millimeters (mm), centimeters (cm), or points (pt). If no units are specified, points are assumed. Examples: "210mm", "8.5in".

Comment: maybe... PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.Custom
             PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.CustomPdfPageSize = new SizeF(widthInPoints, heightInPoints)  from http://www.expertpdf.net/fine-tunning-of-html-to-pdf-conversion-with-expertpdf/

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the VB.net but here is the solution:

```
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf.PdfPageSize.Custom
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.CustomPdfPageSize = New Drawing.SizeF(432, 648)
```

These rows will produce a 6x9in .pdf. I used https://www.asknumbers.com/inches-to-points.aspx for conversions.